# Listview changes the position of other views on keyboard open

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have created android screen with `LinearLayout` in which I have used layout_sum property for screen division. In that created one `EditText` for search in ListView it seems ok before opening soft keyboard.
But when I open the soft keyboard `EditText` get hide like shows in images.

Here is my xml code.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4" >
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="T100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="A100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="P100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="S100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4" >
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/lvdetail"
                    android:text="Search :" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
    
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/eatmcode"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="2"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="Enter ATM"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textSize="16dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="2"/>
            </LinearLayout> 
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtSearch"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="List of Vehicle"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" /> 
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.1"
            android:transcriptMode="normal" >
        </ListView>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Screen before Keyboard open

[image]

after Keyboard open

[image]

Any Help will be appriciated. Thank You.

Comment: when keyboard shown, the area of your app is only the upper part of the screen, and as you used weight, both the list view and the view above shrink

Comment: can you give some example?

Comment: so, you mean we don't have to use weight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use weight on the LinearLayout above the ListView, i.e. use fixed height, and set weight as 1 for the ListView.

**Edit:**

sample code:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:transcriptMode="normal" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your current activity tag on manifest file.

Comment: but it hides listview behind keyboard

Comment: You can add your list-view in Scroll-View for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your manifest file

in your activity tag add like below

```
<activity
    android:name="com.companyname.applicationname"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)  for more info

Comment: but it hides listview behind keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Remove weight in listView and LinearLayout use wrap_content like this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="T100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="A100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="P100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="S100"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:text="Search :" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/eatmcode"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="2"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="Enter ATM"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textSize="16dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="2"/>
            </LinearLayout> 

           <!--  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtSearch"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="List of Vehicle"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" /> -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:transcriptMode="normal" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```